# Chrome Dark Mode - Improve behaviour

Tags: google-chrome, color-theme, flag

I'm running Chrome on Windows 10.  Windows is running in dark mode, and I've enabled the `chrome://flags/#enable-force-dark` flag for Chrome (set to `Enabled`, rather than any of the more complex options).

Most of the time it behaves exactly as I'd like, but there are a lot of sites where dark mode makes it hard to see icons (e.g. Google's own Gmail; even if I amend the Gmail theme).  I'm surprised that Google's own products don't play well with this feature, so thought I may be missing a trick...

- Does Windows Dark Mode have some impact on Chrome's Dark Mode?
- Is there a way to set Chrome to prefer a Dark Mode theme when one's present (i.e. it looks like CSS developers can flag their stylesheets for this (`prefers-color-scheme: dark`).  Does Chrome have a handshake to not apply it's own theme if one's given / only force dark mode if there's no such preference?: `prefers-color-scheme: dark`).
- Is there any setting/flag/config which helps ensure you're generally in dark mode, but that works well in sites like Gmail and GitHub?

Comment: Note: I had a play with the various options available for that flag & found that `enabled with selective image inversion` seems to work best.  Some sites look awful; it's a shame there's no option to pick a preferred mode per site; but for the vast majority of scenarios this seems to behave as desired.

Comment: You could try pasting `chrome://settings/manageProfile` into the navigation bar of your web browser, and see if you can choose a theme from there. For me, this works in Google Chrome, but unfortunately not in the latest version of the Iridium browser.